# React.Component page load approach

Tags: webpack, reactjs

I'm just getting started with React after using Angular for a few years and trying to figure out the best approach for loading components that generally will make some calls to web services and render the result.

I've got a web forms solution I'm adding React to. I've got a React.Component class that gets some data from a separate class using promises and then renders the result:

```
export default class TestControl extends React.Component<TestProps, TestState> {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);       
    this.state = { data: [] };
}

componentDidMount() {
    Data.GetData().then((result) => {
        this.setState((prevState, props) => {
            return { data: result };
        });
    });
}    

render() {
    return(
        <header>
            <div>
                {this.state.data.map(function (item, index) {
                    return <p>{item.title}</p>
                })
                }
            </div>
        </header>
    );        
    }
}
```

I'm also using webpack to bundle the solution. The webpack.config is pretty standard, with the entry being a .tsx. Which looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestComponent from "./components/TestComponent";
import * as $ from 'jquery'

$(document).ready(function () {
    ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent />, document.getElementById("test-component"));
});
```

So my understanding here is that webpack wont bundle anything that isn't referenced and used in this file. Also that, unlike angular, there's no custom identifier I can put on my .aspx page like ng-controller="x" where I want the control to render, I have to have a normal DOM element on the page and then use ReactDOM.render passing in the element's ID to get my control to fire.

I obviously want my control to load as quickly as possible so my bundle .js is in the < head > below my react.js reference. The problem with this was that ReactDOM.render was firing before my element was on the page, so I've had to introduce a dom.ready but this obviously isn't the best.

I'm now contemplating separating out my component class so that the data is retrieved separately (so I can fire it as soon as the JS is hit) and then passed into React.Component via state/props once DOM is ready. But would this be the correct approach? Although this would still mean I'd have to wait until the entire DOM was ready before I could pass this data into the control for render so I'm guessing this isn't the best.

I have just dived into this so am probably way off in a number of areas here, but would appreciate a pointer or two in the right direction.

Thanks.

**Update**

To word my issue in another way:

In a basic page I'd have a top navigation. In Angular I'd have a controller, some services and bundle those into a custom JS file. Then in the markup:

```
<head>
<script for custom JS>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="topNav">
```

From creating an equivalent solution in React, because I have to call ReactDOM.render and pass in the element, the JS for the custom React class has to be referenced after the DOM element. So although my top navigation code and supporting services will be needed on every page, I'll need to separate out the top nav component class (or at least the ReactDOM.render call to it) and the supporting classes into different JS files. As otherwise I'll be loading all JS late on in the page load (bottom of ) when the supporting classes could have been loaded earlier in the head. So my markup looks like this:

```
<head>
<script with custom JS bundled by webpack with supporting React classes>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top-nav">
<script with top nav code and call to ReactDOM.render(<TopNav />, document.getElementById("top-nav")>
```

Have I got the approach correct here? It just feels like this may take longer to load compared to Angular, as Angular seems to fire ng-controller as soon as it appears? Or definitely before DOM ready at least. And also all of the JS can go in 1 bundle file. Where as the only options here are to load the JS after the DOM element or bundle it into the head JS but only call ReactDOM.render in a jQuery(document).ready() so we can ensure the element ReactDOM.render is reliant upon is there.

It all works so far with a top nav element and seems quick enough but having to reference separate JS at bottom of the body instead of the head would surely add a delay compared to loading it all in the head? I just wanted to check I wasn't missing something with how to add components in React.

Comment: Since the data is required on page load there's nothing wrong with requesting it before you do anything with react. I think that's a pretty crazy constraint though considering the ajax call will likely take far longer than loading the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I'm not going wrong in how I'm adding the component? It just feels like it may cause slower load compared to ng-controller which seems to get kicked off as soon as the page finds it (although I'm not sure if this is better in performance than referencing a HTML element and then a JS file with a React component in it).

Comment: Angular isn't faster and it doesn't have anything to do with `ng-controller`. Angular doesn't run any controller functions until the document is ready, it just does it for you. The best thing to do, is put all your scripts at the bottom of the body, load the DOM right away, show a loading spinner, then clear the spinner once the ajax request has come back.

Comment: Appreciate the responses. I've updated my question to word it in another way. My understanding is you'd always want to bundle JS in as small a number of files as possible and also load it as early as possible in the markup, hopefully my updated answer shows why I can't do this in React which is what I feel the issue is. I also do believe Angular fires ng-controller code before the DOM ready as often people try and implement non-Angular plugins and have to use $timeout(function(){}, 0) to execute after DOM added.